# Best approach to make a reverse five-star rating calculator

Tags: python, algorithm

In the 5-star rating system, I have a known number of ratings N (Votes.)
I also have the final (weighted) average of all those N ratings, let's say it is R (float to two decimal places).
I would like to know the best approach (Algorithm) to generate all possible combinations (Total of weighted averages) and print out only the one(s) which result in R. Printing "ALL" possible combinations is not what I am looking for, because it will run in the tens of billions for a large N and small R. I am one step removed from being a python newbie, but it will be the language of choice, and this very exercise is my introduction to the language. What is the best approach to this problem? Approach is my question, but any hint of code is greatly appreciated.

**Example:**

N= 20 customers rated a product
R = 3.85 is the average rating

The Output:
[14, 0, 0, 1, 5]
is one possible combination out of 146.
"14 five-stars, 0 four-stars, 0 three-stars, 1 two-stars, and 5 one-star"

And the combination:
[487, 0, 1, 0, 12]
is one possible combination out of 1154 for N=500 and R=4.90 etc.,.

Comment: This question has nothing in particular to do with Python. You probably need an algorithm.

Comment: Looks like homework, and as you tagged it with Python maybe show us your best trial, and someone may help to find where you are stuck.

Comment: Why can't you evenly re-distribute the average? For example, how would you have any idea given just the average and total that you had 10 five-stars, 4 four-stars, etc?

Comment: @cricket_007 That's not the point. He wants every combination that results in the given average.

Comment: There are 146 integral solutions to N=20, N*R=77, you really need to find all of them?

Comment: Is brute-force enough?

Comment: @kennytm I'm curious as to how you got that number.

Comment: @Nelxiost that number is correct according to my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of stars is N*R (20 * 3.85 =  77 in your example).  Now what you have similar to [the change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) except that your total number of coins is fixed.

An efficient solution might be to start with as many large coins (5 star ratings) as would not exceed the total, and decrease until you have ratings that would not make the total.  You still end up checking solutions that don't work, but it will be significantly faster than checking all solutions, especially for large problem sizes.

Here is my solution: (EDIT: Solution debugged.  I don't think its the optimal solution, but its better than brute force.  1931 recursive calls for the sample case of N=20 R=3.85)

```
def distribution(total, maxRating, N, solution):
    if total == 0 and N == 0:
        return [solution + [0] * maxRating] #we found a solution

    if total == 0 or N == 0:
        return [] # no solution possible

    largestUpperLimit = min(total // maxRating, N) # an upper limit for the number of reviews with the largest rating
    largestLowerLimit = max((total - N * (maxRating -1)) // maxRating, 0) # a lower limit for the number of reviews with the largest rating

    if N < largestLowerLimit:
        return [] # there aren't enough ratings to make any solutions
    else:
        solutions = []
        for i in range(largestLowerLimit, largestUpperLimit + 1): # plus 1 to include the upper limit
            solutions.extend(distribution(total - i * maxRating, maxRating - 1, N - i, solution + [i]))
        return solutions


# Using the function example:
solutions = distribution(N * R, 5, N, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

(inefficient) Brute force solution.

Note: Can make more efficient by replacing `product(range(0, N+1), repeat=5)` with something else that can generate a list of 5 numbers that sum to N.

Find all lists of length 5 (for the ratings) up to N, then calculate the weighted average and compare against R. Print the lists as you go

```
from itertools import product

def weighed_avergage(l, total):
    if sum(l) != total:
        return 0
    return sum(rating * stars for rating, stars in zip(l, range(5, 0, -1))) / float(total)

N = 20
R = 3.85

for p in product(range(0, N+1), repeat=5):
    w_avg = weighed_avergage(p, N)
    if w_avg == R:
        print p
```

Should see `(10, 4, 1, 3, 2)` in the output, which corresponds to your question of 10 five-stars, 4 four-stars, 1 three-stars, 3 two-stars, and 2 one-star

Comment: Is `p` supposed to be the distribution of votes, i.e. `(4,3,1,6,2)` meaning 4 5-star-votes, 3 4-star votes, and so on? In this case, I think this does not work.

Comment: Yes, the permutation of the number of ratings in descending orders of stars. Why does that not work?

Comment: Well, unless I am terribly misunderstanding something, this can create `p` like `(0,1,2,3,4)`, or `(20,19,18,...)`, neither of which sums to 20. Also, it could _not_ generate `p` like `(4,4,4,4,4)`, or `(0,0,0,0,20)`.

Comment: Updated answer does generate `(0,0,0,0,20)`. Regarding the sums to 20 - yes, I am aware that there are more values generated than necessary.

Comment: Number of matching distributions is correct, but it tries a total of 4084101 to get there.

Comment: Like, I said, I am aware it is not optimal :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all the distributions of votes using a recursive algorithm and then check which of those have correct weighted average. But note that the number of combinations grows quickly.

```
def distributions(ratings, remaining):
    if len(ratings) > 1:
        # more than one rating: take some for first and distribute rest
        for n in range(remaining+1):
            for dist in distributions(ratings[1:], remaining - n):
                yield [(ratings[0], n)] + dist
    elif len(ratings) == 1:
        # only one rating left -> all remaining go there
        yield [(ratings[0], remaining)]
    else:
        # should never happen
        raise ValueError("No more ratings left")

def weighted_avg(votes):
    return sum(r * n for r, n in votes) / sum(n for r, n in votes)

for dist in distributions([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 20):
    if weighted_avg(dist) == 3.85:
        print(dist)
```

In total there are `10626` distributions, and `146` of those yield the correct average. Output (some):

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 3), (4, 17), (5, 0)]
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 4), (4, 15), (5, 1)]
...
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 10)]
...
[(1, 5), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 13)]
[(1, 5), (2, 1), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 14)]
```

Comment: I doubt brute force is the best solution.

Comment: @WolfLink Totally agreed, and anxious to see a better solution. ;-)

Comment: Still reasonably fast for N=60, though (635376 total, 2767 correct).Curiously, there seems to be no fitting distribution for N=10, 30, 50, 70,etc..

Comment: My version only had 61617 recursive calls for the N=60 case (this feels like some sort of code golf lol).  I'm pretty sure its still not optimal though.

Comment: @tobias_k: If N is 10, the ratings have to add up to 38.5, which is impossible since half-stars are not permitted. Or do you mean N to mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that doesn't use brute force. The indented code shows an example.

You have the number of ratings N and their average R.
Let `si` be the number of i-stars ratings (with `i in [1..5]`).
We have `s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 = N`.
We also have `s1 + 2*s2 + 3*s3 + 4*s4 + 5*s5 = R*N`.

```
  s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 = 20
  s1 + 2*s2 + 3*s3 + 4*s4 + 5*s5 = 77
```

Hence `s2 + 2*s3 + 3*s4 + 4*s5 = R*N - N`.
Now choose a value for `s1` and calculate `s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 = N - s1`.

```
  s2 + 2*s3 + 3*s4 + 4*s5 = 57
  s1 = 4
  s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 = 16
```

We can continue with `s3 + 2*s4 + 3*s5 = (R*N - N) - (N - s1)`.
Choose a value for `s2` and calculate `s3 + s4 + s5 = N - s1 - s2`.

```
  s3 + 2*s4 + 3*s5 = 41
  s2 = 2
  s3 + s4 + s5 = 14
```

Repeat with `s3` and get the value for `s5` and `s4`.

```
  s4 + 2*s5 = 27
  s3 = 9
  s4 + s5 = 5

  s5 = 22
  s4 = -17
```

Now, obviously, this produces incorrect solutions (in the example, `s5 > 20` and `s4 < 0`). In order to avoid that, we can constrain the value choices each time.
We need to choose `s3` so that `s4 + s5 >= (s4 + 2*s5)/2`, so that we end up with `s5 <= s4 + s5`.
This is possible only if `s3 + s4 + s5 >= (s3 + 2*s4 + 3*s5)/3`, hence another constraint, this time for `s2`.
And finally, the constraint for `s1` is `s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 >= (s2 + 2*s3 + 3*s4 + 4*s5)/4`.

Comment: If anyone implements that in python, I'd be glad to include it. I'm not experienced enough in that language to provide a clear solution.

Comment: This is basically how my algorithm works.  See my answer.

Comment: @WolfLink I would doubt it. My algorithm doesn't make thousands of recursive calls. And even then, if you get 2767 solutions for the example problem, your algorithm is wrong.

Comment: 2767 was for the N=60 case presented by tobias_k.  My algorithm determines a range of values for s5, then for each value in that range recurses and finds a range of values for s4, etc.  It's very similar although I think your method is a bit more streamlined.